# Determining a mix of clusters by using naive Bayes classifiers

Tags: probability, classification, matlab, naive-bayes

I have the following question which I cannot seem to find an easy answer to: given that we have two groups (let's call them 1 and 2), is it possible to determine a mixed percentage of the groups by training on only 1 and 2?

For example, I did two clusters like this:

```
clusterSize = 1000;
% cluster one
cluster1 = randn(clusterSize, 2);
cluster1L = ones(clusterSize, 1);
% cluster two
cluster2 = randn(clusterSize, 2) + 5;
cluster2L = 2 * ones(clusterSize, 1);
```

I can then define clusters 3, 4 and 5, such that:

- 3 is a 50/50 combination of 1 and 2
- 4 is a 25/75 combination of 1 and 2
- 5 is a 75/25 combination of 1 and 2

To do this, here is the code:

```
% cluster three
cluster3 = 0.5.*cluster1 + 0.5.*cluster2;
cluster3L = 3 * ones(clusterSize, 1);
% cluster four
cluster4 = 0.25.*cluster1 + 0.75.*cluster2;
cluster4L = 4 * ones(clusterSize, 1);
% cluster five
cluster5 = 0.75.*cluster1 + 0.25.*cluster2;
cluster5L = 5 * ones(clusterSize, 1);
```

I then return this data as a table:

```
X = [cluster1; cluster2; cluster3; cluster4; cluster5];
Y = string([cluster1L; cluster2L; cluster3L; cluster4L; cluster5L]);
Data = table();
Data.X = X(:,1);
Data.Y = X(:,2);
Data.Label = Y;
```

I normalize and take the PCA of the data. I train only on clusters 1 and 2:

```
predictors = normalize(Data{:,1:2});
[coeff, score, latent, tsquared, explained] = pca(predictors);
TrainingClustersData = score(contains(Data.Label,["1", "2"]),:);
TrainingLabels = Data.Label(contains(Data.Label,["1", "2"]),:);
MixedClustersData = score(~contains(Data.Label,["1", "2"]),:);
MixedClustersLabels = Data.Label(~contains(Data.Label,["1", "2"]),:);
mdl = fitcnb(TrainingClustersData, TrainingLabels);
```

Doing so, I can calculate the posterior probability of the clusters and I can also scatter the different clusters to check their location:

```
xMax = 5;
xMin = -5;
h = 0.05;
[x1Grid,x2Grid] = meshgrid(xMin:h:xMax,xMin:h:xMax);
[~,PosteriorRegion] = predict(mdl,[x1Grid(:),x2Grid(:)]);
PosteriorRegion(:,3) = 0;
h = scatter(x1Grid(:),x2Grid(:),1,PosteriorRegion);
xlim([xMin xMax])
ylim([xMin xMax])
hold on
gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), Data.Label)
legend("Location", "northwest")
```

By checking the plot, I can see that the distances of the clusters heavily depend on the mix that I defined previously, which is logical.

[image: Posterior]

My question is, can I find this mix percentage from this approach? is this viable and can it be found in citable research? Using `mdl.predict` on the mix data gives me probabilities (scores) of the sample belonging to either cluster 1 or 2, which is also what I need in this case. I want to use this probability as a mix determination.

I look forward to any comments, critiques or suggestions

Comment: The magic words were "[mixture models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model)" and "[probabilistic models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic words were "[mixture models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model)" and "[probabilistic models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model)". To elaborate more, after literature research and a few trials with different algorithms, I decided that Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) would be the best type of model that I could use for my particular case.

To start, I generated data, as is described in [this MATLAB tutorial](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/cluster-gaussian-mixture-data-using-soft-clustering.html):

```
sigma = [10 0.5; 0.5 10]; % the a bit exaggerated covariance matrix
mu1 = [-4 0]; % mean of cluster 1
mu2 = [4 0]; % mean of cluster 2
cluster1 = mvnrnd(mu1,sigma,100); % generate the multivariate random data for the first cluster
cluster2 = mvnrnd(mu2,sigma,100);  % generate the multivariate random data for the second cluster
X = [cluster1; cluster2]; % concat for the training
```

Now I define the same kind of percentages as before, given the data in `cluster1` and in `cluster2`:

```
Middle = 0.5.*cluster1 + 0.5.*cluster2; % 50/50 mix
Left = 0.75.*cluster1 + 0.25.*cluster2; % 75/25 mix of cluster 1 and cluster 2
Right = 0.25.*cluster1 + 0.75.*cluster2; % 25/75 mix of cluster 1 and cluster 2
```

Now that I have the data, I can train on the first two "pure" clusters using the [`fitgmdist` MATLAB function](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitgmdist.html):

```
gmSharedDiag = fitgmdist(X,2,'CovType','Diagonal', 'SharedCovariance',true);
```

As suggested in the tutorial, the decision to use a shared covariance or not depends on the shape of the clusters. As I am currently using the same covariance matrix `sigma` to generate both clusters, I will go with a shared covariance. This will most probably not apply to my real-life data.

From here, I can finally apply the clustering on the data:

```
% get the clustering of the GMM model along with posterior probability
% the posterior probability is what I want!
[idxSharedDiag,~,PSharedDiag] = cluster(gmSharedDiag,X);
[~,orderSharedDiag] = sort(PSharedDiag(:,1));
% apply the clustering on the left, middle and right clusters
[idxSharedDiagLeft,~,PSharedDiagLeft] = cluster(gmSharedDiag,Left);
[idxSharedDiagMiddle,~,PSharedDiagMiddle] = cluster(gmSharedDiag,Middle);
[idxSharedDiagRight,~,PSharedDiagRight] = cluster(gmSharedDiag,Right);
```

As mentioned before, I am mainly interested in getting the posterior probability and seeing if it somehow reflects the original mixture that I specified. To start, we can check the probability score of the original two clusters, since they have overlap. Here we can clearly see that while some points score very highly on either clusters, others lay exactly in the middle and hence this stops being discrete C1 or C2, but a mix of both. This can also be achieved with naive Bayes approach.

[image: Sorted probability scores of cluster 1 and 2]

Checking the clustering of the three other clusters shows that indeed, there is a pattern. The cluster `Left` (75% C1, 25% C2) has more points clustered as cluster 1 than in cluster 2. The opposite can be said about `Right` and `Middle` lies exactly in the middle.

[image: Clusters based on the left, middle and right data]

Finally, we can check their probabilities for each cluster and we see the desired pattern, where the means of the scores reflect the original mix percentage, or at least the pattern of it, which is my end goal:

[image: Probabilities of the clusters]

I will further explore different approaches to optimize the model, by looking at the AIC or BIC and checking what parameters minimize these values. I will look into [this book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471721182) as well to get familiar with the theory and other applications of mixture models.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/364437)

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand sure thing, i'll do a bit of lit research on Monday and link some relevant papers and passages. Thanks for the revision!

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, I have marked it as _looks Ok_ at low quality posts queue, only because OP has assured they would add further materials in their post coming Monday or so forth. Otherwise, it can be dealt with possible flag and altogether deletion later.

Comment: @User1865345 generally so I know what to edit in my answer, is it more interesting on crossvalidated to address the theory of the approach only or also the programming?

Comment: You can add both necessary to the topic in question. Addressing both from statistical as well as programming pov would rather make a comprehensive post.